# Converting date to mothname, day, year with like() codeigniter 4

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-4

I'm using ci4 and I want to get the month name on search with like() method:

I tried this but did not work:

table column = p.date = '2021-05-18 01:07:50'

```
$this->like(date('F', strtotime('p.date')), date('F', strtotime('18-05-2021'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//createdon - 2020-06-15 02:19:40
$this->db->where('month(createdon)',6);
$result = $this->db->get('yourtablename')->result();
```

Comment: Thanks, But I mean using it inside like() method. Is it possible?

Comment: $this->db->like('month(createdon)',6);